# Manage JSON File - Struct or Class?

Tags: ios, json, swiftui

I wanted to ask a question about my doubt.

I'm currently implementing my code for decoding a `JSON` file using two structures for the data model and one `FriendsManager` class for data management

In your opinion is this a good approach or should I work with `structs` instead of using a `class`?

I'm new to decoding `JSON` files and wanted to make sure I was writing my code the right way

```
private let JSONFriendFileName = "Friends"

class FriendsManager: ObservableObject {

    var friendsList: [FriendsList] = []
    
    init() {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        decode(fileName: JSONFriendFileName, decoder: decoder)
    }
    
     func decode(fileName: String, decoder: JSONDecoder) {
        
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: JSONFriendFileName, withExtension: "json") else {
            print("Non esiste alcun file denominato \(JSONFriendFileName + ".json") in questo progetto")
            return
        }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let items = try decoder.decode(Friends.self, from: data)

            friendsList = items.friendsList

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

struct Friends: Codable {
    var friendsList: [FriendsList]
}

struct FriendsList: Codable, Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let timestamp: Int?
    let contact_info: String?
    
    let id = UUID()
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, timestamp, contact_info
    }
}
```

---

Data usage

```
import SwiftUI

struct FriendsView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var friendsManager = FriendsManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(friendsManager.friendsList) { friends in
                    Text(friends.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Friends")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only a class can conform to ObservableObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, answer is complicated because it depends on how do you plan to use `Friends` and `FriendsList` objects. `struct` is immutable, `class` is mutable. Read more about differences [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/classesandstructures/).

I would say if you do NOT plan to modify `FriendsList` later in the app - use `struct`. If you plan to modify it later in the app, there are few options:

- use `struct` and create another objects with the same data, which will be modified later instead.
- use `class` and modify it later.

Both of those create additional complications - you have to store changes somewhere, which leads to question where and how (database, backend, etc.).

Also at your place I would rename `FriendsList` struct to `Friend`, because it represents a single object (friend) and not a list. Otherwise it is a bit confusing name.

```
struct Friends: Codable {
    var friendsList: [Friend]
}

struct Friend: Codable, Identifiable {
...
}
```